# Java-trying to add two numbers by taking input from user and calling the function through the main method

Tags: java

I have created this code. When I try to run it it's not working. It's not returning the answer. Can anyone help me out??
I am trying to do arithmetic operations on the numbers by taking input from users:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Earth {
    int a,b,c;
    Scanner d=new Scanner(System.in);
    public void entry()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a");
        a=d.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter b");
        b=d.nextInt();

    }
    public void sum(){
        c=a+b;
        System.out.println("The sum is" +c);
    }
    public void difference(){
        c=a-b;
        System.out.println("The ans is" +c);
    }
    public void div(){
        c=a/b;
        System.out.println("The ans is" +c);
    }
    public void multi(){
        c=a*b;
        System.out.println("The ans is" +c);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Earth e=new Earth();
        Earth e1=new Earth();
        System.out.println("Enter any one sum,div,diff,mul");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String r=sc.next();
        e.entry();
        String sum=null;
        String mul = null;
        String diff = null;
        String div = null;
        if(r==sum)
        {
            e1.sum();
        }

        if(r==mul)
        {
            e1.multi();
        }
        if(r==div)
        {
            e1.div();
        }

        if(r==diff)
        {
            e1.difference();
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you try this? What do you expect to happen? How did you try it out? Is there an error message?

Comment: Those `if` statements don't look good. Compare `Strings` with `.equal` instead and be sure to initialize your comparison values with something different than `null`.

Comment: Your `mul, sum, diff` is `null` I think it must be `mul = "mul"; sum = "sum"`. Then `command = in.nextLine(); if(command.equals(sum) { ... })`

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing variables a,b using reference 'e' and you are calling sum using reference 'e1' and there is one more mistake,should be like

```
    if(r.equals("sum"))
    {
        e1.sum();
    }
```